# Component ID: TSSOP10 93TI AVE

Tags: identification

I'm trying to diagnose a dead Total Phase USB 480 protocol analyser, the unit fails to power on.

When powering from a bench power supply (5 V, current limit set to 500 mA), it is current limiting at an output voltage of ~1.05 V. When this happens the part labelled 93TI AVE gets hot. There's no silk screen on the PCB to suggest what it is, and there's little surrounding circuitry suggesting what role it's playing.

Any ideas what this component might be?[image]

Comment: For the close vote, I'm not asking how to repair it, I'm asking for a part ID which I do believe is allowed on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the TI **[TPS60503DGS High-Efficiency, 250-mA Step-Down Charge Pump](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps60503.pdf)**  with 1.5 V fixed output.

The datasheet shows it's a VSSOP 10-pin package matching the photo (datasheet page 24 shows the **AVE** marking, see image below).

While we can't follow all the PCB tracks in the photo, capacitors C209 and C210 in the photo match the overall topology used by that device, with its 2 flying capacitors (these are labeled C1F and C2F in the typical schematic below).

[image: Typical application circuit from the linked TI datasheet]

[image: Packaging info from the linked TI datasheet]

(Images are from the TI datasheet linked above.)